# ndb.StructuredProperty does not save the key?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

If we have the usual blog post webapp where many users can post blog entries, but we also want to retrieve all entries from a single user, I would imagine the following data structure:

```
class Blog_Entries(ndb.Model):
    ...

class Users(ndb.Model):
    ...
    blog_entries = ndb.StructuredProperty(Blog_Entries, repeated=True)
    ...
```

However, the issue is that when you copy a "Blog_Entries" object into Users.blog_entries, the key is lost (not copied over from the original instance). This makes it troublesome to update both posts and maintain consistency.

Is there any way of avoiding this? Is there a better strategy to approach the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: by using `StructuredProperty` there is no key for the instances of the property, they become part of the actual entity containing them. what exactly do you mean by `copy a "Blog_Entries" object into Users.blog_entries`? do you move blog entries from one `User` to the other? (i would use singular names for the models not plural like you used here, every class describes the structure of a single entity)

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You could subclass `StructuredProperty` and override it's `_serialize()` and `_deserialize()` methods to also serialize/deserialize the key. You can use `KeyProperty` to handle the serialization of the key. ;-)</strike>

I just found out that `LocalStructuredProperty` has an option `keep_keys`. As the name of the option implies, it stores the key of the nested model.

```
class Organization(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Employee(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    organization = ndb.LocalStructuredProperty(Organization,
                                               keep_keys=True)

linux_foundation = Organization(name='Linux Foundation')
linux_foundation.put()
linus = Employee(name='Linus Torvalds', organization=linux_foundation)
linus_key = linus.put()

ndb.get_context().clear_cache()
linus = linus_key.get()
assert linus.organization.key.get().name == 'Linux Foundation'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try blog_entries = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="Blog_Entries", repeated=True)